# How to Edit a row in Datatable .net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, datatables

I try to update a row in my datatable with .net core. Datatable show data and have a new/delete button that works. But when I try to edit a row, I can't get it to work.

Here is mi index.cshtml. Thanks

```json
"ajax": {
  "url": "../LoadIntervaloTrabajo",
  "type": "POST",
  "data": { "codigo": @Model.codigo},
  "datatype": "json"
  },
  "columns": [
     { "data": "horario", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "codigo", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "descripcion", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "horainicio", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "duracion", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "cortentrada", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "cortintermedia", "autowidth": true },
     { "data": "cortsalida", "autowidth": true },
     { "render": function (data, type, row) { 
                     return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick=EditData('" + row.codigo + "'); >Editar</a>"; 
                                                   }
                     },
                 function EditData(codigo) {
                       var table = $("#customerDatatable").DataTable();
                       var r = table.rows(".selected").nodes()[0];
                       if ($(table.buttons(".editButton")[0].node).find("span").text() == "Cancel") {
                           $(r).children("td").each(function (i, it) {
                                if (i > 0) {
                                    var od = table.cells(it).data()[0];
                                    $(it).html(od);
                                }
                           });                                              
                           setButtons('cancel');
                       } else {
                           $(r).children("td").each(function (i, it) {
                                if (i > 0) {
                                    var h = $("<input type='text'>");
                                    h.val(it.innerText);
                                    $(it).html(h);
                                }
                           });
                           setButtons('edit');
                       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to update a row in my datatable with .net core.

To implement updating row functionality, you can refer to the following code snippet.

*Render two buttons for updating row within the last column*

```
"columns": [
    {
        "data": "horario", "autowidth": true
    },
    { "data": "codigo", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "descripcion", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "horainicio", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "duracion", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "cortentrada", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "cortintermedia", "autowidth": true },
    { "data": "cortsalida", "autowidth": true },
    {
        "render": function (data, type, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick = EditData(this); >Editar</a><a href='#' class='btn btn-info btn-hidden' onclick = UpdateData(this); >Updatear</a>"; }
    }
]
```

*JS function*

```
function EditData(btnedit) {
    //find current row
    var $row = $(btnedit).parent().parent();
    var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':nth-child(2)').not(':last');

    $.each($tds, function (i, el) {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).html("").append("<input type='text' value=\"" + txt + "\">");
    });
    $(btnedit).siblings("a").removeClass("btn-hidden");
    $(btnedit).addClass("btn-hidden");
}

function UpdateData(btnupdate) {
    var $row = $(btnupdate).parent().parent();

    var horario = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").find("input").val();
    var codigo = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    var descripcion = $row.find("td:nth-child(3)").find("input").val();
    var horainicio = $row.find("td:nth-child(4)").find("input").val();
    var duracion = $row.find("td:nth-child(5)").find("input").val();
    var cortentrada = $row.find("td:nth-child(6)").find("input").val();
    var cortintermedia = $row.find("td:nth-child(7)").find("input").val();
    var cortsalida = $row.find("td:nth-child(8)").find("input").val();


    var data_for_update = { "horario": horario, "codigo": codigo, "descripcion": descripcion, "horainicio": horainicio, "duracion": duracion, "cortentrada": cortentrada, "cortintermedia": cortintermedia, "cortsalida": cortsalida };

    //console.log(data_for_update);

    //make request to update data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/{controller_name_here}/Update",
        data: JSON.stringify(data_for_update),
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
            var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':nth-child(2)').not(':last');

            $.each($tds, function (i, el) {
                var txt = $(this).find("input").val()
                $(this).html(txt);
            });
            $(btnupdate).siblings("a").removeClass("btn-hidden");
            $(btnupdate).addClass("btn-hidden");
        },
        //...
    });


            
}
```

*CSS style*

```
.btn-hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Test Result

[image]